# CGRect "does not contain point" objective-c

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView within a RootViewController and when a cell is tapped I want it to chance colour but only one should be enabled at one time.

I'm having difficulty trying to say "if CGRect does not contain tap".

```
.m

- (void)changeColour:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    if (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded == tap.state) {
        UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)tap.view;
        CGPoint p = [tap locationInView:tap.view];
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        CGPoint pointInCell = [tap locationInView:cell];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(cell.frame, p)) {
            UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
                       view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
                       [cell setBackgroundView:view1];

        } else  {
                       UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
                       view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                       [cell setBackgroundView:view1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: CGRectContainsPoint(cell.frame, p) only work first cell,p is a table view point,other cell frames are started origin (0,0),change cell.frame to tableView.frame

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to not to use gestures...

Use TableView Delegate methods...

To use this make sure you have assign delegates to your tableview..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell setBackgroundView:view1];
    [view1 release];//for NON ARC ONLY
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell setBackgroundView:view1];
    [view1 release];//for NON ARC ONLY
}
```

This will definitely help you

Enjoy coding........

Comment: Thank you and this goes in TableViewAppDelegate?

Comment: Still working on it.I've added the <UITableViewDelegate> and put the methods in the .m file.

Comment: if it is working then accept this answer. It would be helpful for other users.

Comment: I just realised the function is not being called. Any advice on setting the delegate? I thought declaring it in the .h would do it but do I need a tableView.delegate=self?  Thanks for the help

Comment: what are you using xib or story board?

Comment: make sure that you have bind delegates from the xib. or you have written `tableView.delegate = self;` in `viewDidLoad`